# Add the synonym list-processing to the tag list-manipulation

Tags: support, status-completed, tag-synonyms

Per a discussion on [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3041073#3041073), we'd like to use [list-manipulation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/list-manipulation) as it is the phrase used in the documentation, but [list-processing](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/list-processing) is a good synonym for it. Unfortunately, at the moment, no-one has synonym capability.

Answer (score 2):

All done. [list-processing](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/list-processing) now redirects to [list-manipulation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/list-manipulation).